# What is the meaning of "tough little number"

Tags: meaning, vocabulary

According to longman dict, little number is a dress or suit of woman. But I can't get the meaning of the word "tough" in this phrase.

Here is the context:

https://www.msn.com/en-xl/northamerica/northamerica-life-arts/30-incredible-photos-of-animals-in-the-wild/ss-BBS2Mgv?li=BBKxOg5#image=13

Comment: This phrasing sounds weird to me (from America,) but little number can potentially refer to many things including, a musical/dance performance. The "number" here is taking the place of "horse" for some reason.

Comment: _Little number_ can also refer to a person or, in this case, animal. You could substitute "horse" giving _"tough horse"_ .

Comment: I've generally heard "tough little number" used to refer to a person -- someone who is not physically imposing but who seems to have "spunk".  (Speaking as someone from the US Midwest.)

Answer (score 2):

**tough**  [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/203905?rskey=W33jME&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid)

> As an epithet of commendation: very good, ‘great’. U.S. slang (orig.
>   African-American).

From 1937:

> Amer. Speech 12 45/2   I caught Wright's band last night and are they
>   tough.

**little number**  [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/129082?redirectedFrom=little%20number#eid33918604)

> 7. colloquial. Used generally (and frequently humorously) to refer to any person or thing (identified more precisely by context). Frequently
>      in **little number**.

In your cited context:  a great horse!

Answer (score 1):

*Number* can also be a person, not an article of clothing.

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/number):

> slang, sometimes offensive: a person, esp a woman
>   *who's that nice little **number**?*

I could imagine seeing "number" used this way by Archie Goodwin in a Nero Wolfe novel, or by someone in a Raymond Chandler book.

Extending this concept, we get *cute individual*, which in this case is an attractive horse.  This is humorous.  It's kind of like writing a photo caption saying, "Wouldn't you like to take this cutie home with you tonight?"

The *tough* part is because this variety of horse can stand up to the harsh climate in Iceland, according to the source material ("A tough little number:
Having arrived with the first Scandinavian settlers, the Icelandic horse is a small, robust species that is particularly well adapted to the Icelandic climate. Good thing, because in Iceland, the horses stay outside all year round!")